# "angular way" for dynamically adding directives

Tags: angularjs

I’m very impressed with Josh's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/2670142)  about ‘angular way’  and declarative style in client-side.

But can you help me to understand, how to do that:

I have a single-page app with the menubar in the left side, and div container on the right-side.

When user clicking the menu item in the left menubar, on the right side I must to open the new tab with some grid,like this:

[image]

In angular I realized the `<grid>` directive.

When user click menuitem, I must add dynamically this grid directive with params on the right side.

What is the angular way for doing  this functionality?

**Update:** 
I found [article](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/08/14/dynamic-tabs-with-angularjs-and-ui-bootstrap.aspx) about dynamic tabs, and this is [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/yVAFAk8nFfI45VEsjVZ3?p=preview) how I use it in my case

Comment: Ask a concrete question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you asked a general question, let me give you a general answer. It should be helpful :)

AngularJS is **model/data** driven, and if you want to make any change to the UI, the first thing you may think is how to achieve it by changing **data**. Given this idea, we can implement it like this:

1. Define a ng-repeater, which should render tabs for a list of `Tab` objects called `MyTabs`, for instance.
2. When you want to add a new tab, then create a tab object and add/push it to `MyTabs`.
3. AngularJS will magically render it on the UI, thanks to the 2-way data binding.

Comment: sza, thank you, I've dicided using ui-tabs, like here http://plnkr.co/edit/yVAFAk8nFfI45VEsjVZ3?p=preview

Comment: This general answer is extremely helpful! Shame it hasn't reached much attention.